# Compare DataTable and DataGridView and hightlight matching rows in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a database table which contains a list of usernames and their current active location, an integer called `SEQUENCE`.

I get this list of sequence numbers into a datatable with a single column (e.g. "SELECT SEQUENCE FROM TABLE"):

`dtUsers = CLS_USERS.GetUsers(User)`

It excludes the current user, which is why I parse in `User`.

What I then do is loop through the datatable and for each number I want to set the matching row in a datagridview (which also has a SEQUENCE column) to a different colour. This is my current code:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtUsers.Rows
    intSeq = row("SEQUENCE")
    For Each dgv_row As DataGridViewRow In dgvCandList.Rows
        If dgv_row.Cells("CURRENT_SQ").Value = intSeq Then
            dgv_row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        Else 
           dgv_row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Grey
        End If
    Next
Next
```

However, all rows are highlighted rather than just those where `dgv_row.Cells("SV_CURRENT_CAND_SQ").Value = intSeq` is True... I've verified that this loop is working correctly, so it must be `dgv_row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan` which is incorrect?

If so, how should I correctly be assigning the row back colour of specific DataGridRow?

**EDIT: This code works correctly, my issue was related to bug outside this loop causing the BackColor to be sent for everything, and then never setback to default if where BackColor wasn't being set back to the default if it wasn't in dtUsers.**

Comment: iterating all rows is grossly inefficient.  Use the RowPrepaint or CellFormatting event to paint just the row needed.  It isnt clear why the data key to this operation is elsewhere.  You can have unseen columns in the DGV

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow I always feltlike it was but wasn't aware of a better method. Can you expand on how I could use RowPrepaint/CellFormatting in my example? I am aware of hidden columns in a DGV; dgvCandList.row("SEQUENCE") is hidden.